# Is it possible to change $(document) width using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm new to jQuery and HTML so probably this is a very dumb question, but I'm just curious if it is possible to change document or window width using jQuery?

Is something like this possible:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(document).width( $(window).width() );
});
```

Thank you

Comment: Yes. You can certainly set it.

Comment: You cannot change the user's browser window width if that's what you're asking, unless it's a window you own created by `window.open`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I understand it, $(document).width() is read only and will not update the width value. You may have better luck with:

```
$('body').width( $(window).width() );
```

Although this would have no effect unless the root element of your document/page was styled to be larger than the viewport (would eliminate horizontal scrolling).